# Customer password reset unsuccessful

Tags: customer-account, ce-1.9.2.0, password-recovery

I am having an issue where customers are unable to login after successfully completing the password reset process. I'm on version Magento 1.9.2.

I did receive a success message on the frontend after resetting the password - "Your password has been updated.". I also did not see any errors in the system.log or exception.log after going through the reset password process.

I've tried following the directions in the post below, but had no luck. 
http://www.pixelninja.me/magento-password-reset-not-working/

Any help would be much appreciated! Let me know if you'd like any other information.

Comment: Are you able to see anything in the logs when a user attempts to reset their password?

Comment: Any 3rd party extensions installed around customer/account/password management?

Comment: When any one action performs please check the success message showing on the screen. Check the system.log or exception.log file if it displays any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on another question and noticed that customers were also not able to login without doing a password reset. So I did research and came across this post - [Customer Login Doesn't Work in 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31933/customer-login-doesnt-work-in-1-9).

I added this line to the `login.phtml` file:

```
/app/design/frontend/default/template-name/template/persistent/customer/form/
```

and then pasted

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

after

```
<ul class="form-list">
```

Now Customers can login after being logged out and customers can also reset their password as well!