# magento 1.9 customer can not login

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, login

I am using magento 1.9 version site:

http://hotwheelstoys.in/one/em0113-full-package/index.php/

but customer is not able to login to the site.

I tried in all browsers by clearing history. Also I checked in lot of systems. There also I am not able to login.

I followed this

[Customer Login Doesn't Work in 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31933/customer-login-doesnt-work-in-1-9)

but still customer can not able to login to the site.

Comment: Hi, I removed the credentials from your question. Please do not add user logins (frontend or backend) to any websites in questions or answers.

Comment: thanks @AnnaVölkl i iwill not do from next time.....

Comment: Just check if your time zone is set correctly. That could simply be the issue.

Comment: > The trick was to create the directory
> app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model and copy the file Session.php into
> it. The Session.php file can be found at
> app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model. That helped me a lot! Nothing helped, but this! Thank you so much, I just created some folders, made the Session.php file copy into them, corrected it and it worked for me. Lots of thanks!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an issue in the Cookie path and Cookie domain.

Cookie Path should be `/`

Cookie Domain should be `hotwheelstoys.in/one/em0113-full-package`

- `Mage.Cookies.path     = '/';`
- `Mage.Cookies.domain   = '.hotwheelstoys.in/one/em0113-full-package';`

This setting is managed from the admin panel.

So go to **`Admin -> System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Session Cookie Management`** for making required changes.

Comment: hi @amit , can you please explain what changes i have to do in what files ?

Comment: You dont need to touch any files. Amit is aking you to change the configurations. thats it. Backend config.

Comment: Note to self: keep the domain entry blank on the dev machine *facepalm*

Comment: not working....

Comment: @AmitBera I tried your solution and set the configurations but still facing the same issue login and signup not working. Also, the session is not created under the var/session directory. Can you please help me here?

Answer (score 9):

Looks like an issue with `form-key`

1. Go to app/design/frontend/[Your-package]/[Your-theme]/template/customer/form/login.phtml and template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml and under
2. Find: `<ul class=”form-list”>`
3. And paste this right after the code above the following:

   `<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo`     `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />`

Repeat above for app/design/frontend/Your-package]/[Your-theme]/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml

Answer (score 3):

You have to force Magento to use the same cookie domain in all cases. This solution was tested on Magento 1.9.2.4

When the Session Cookie Management variables are not set incorrectly Magento may create two "frontend" cookies with different cookie domains. This typically happens during the login process when you have HTTPS (ie. SSL enabled) for the secure URL. Here are workable values for the Session cookie management configuration.

```
Cookie Life Time: 3600
Cookie Path: /
Cookie Domain : .mydomain.com (The dot prefix is important)
Use HTTP Only : No
Cookie Restriction Mode: No
```

1. In the admin panel go to System -> Configuration -> Web-> Session Cookie Management
2. Set the Cookie Management configuration as shown above
3. Save the configuration and clear the Magento cache
4. Restart your web server to clear the PHP variables in case you made the change directly in MYSQL database
5. Clear your browser cache to remove any existing cookies associated with your magento site.

Using the dot prefix on the cookie domain is important to prevent duplicate cookies from being created for the secure URL

You can inspect your sites cookies using the developer tools in the FireFox or chrome browser.

Changing the cookie domain will also affect the "adminhtml" cookie used by the Magento back end. Make sure to clear your browser cache to prevent admin login problems.

Comment: Why not using "HTTP Only" ?
It is flagged as unsafe by magento

Comment: Setting "Use HTTP Only" to "No"  lets you use the same cookie for secure and unsecure URLs. This is helpful during the checkout process when you allow HTTP for front end URLs. It avoids confusing the customer when they navigate through your site.

Comment: If you force all customers to use HTTPS then you can also change "Use HTTP Only"  to "Yes"

Answer (score 3):

100% solution

The trick was to create the directory `app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model` and copy the file `Session.php` into it.

The `Session.php` file can be found at `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model`.

Once the file is moved over, find this section:

```
public function setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)
{
    $this->setCustomer($customer);
    $this->renewSession();
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));
    return $this;
}
```

Comment out the `$this->renewSession( );` section, so the code looks like this:

```
public function setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)
{
    $this->setCustomer($customer);
    // $this->renewSession();
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));
    return $this;
}
```

Make sure to clear out all login cookies. I tested this on **Chrome**, **Firefox**, and **IE** in Windows, and **Safari** on iPad and everything worked like a charm.

Comment: till not working...

Comment: Its working on magento

Comment: 100 % Not Working.

Answer (score 1):

**New answer to stale question:**

Something went wrong with Google's Invisible reCaptcha today and some customers couldn't log in. This Q/A showed while I was searching on today's *Magento customers cant order* problem. Disabling invisible reCaptcha fixed the site.

If you find yourself here because customers can't log in, try a different browser (because cache and cookies can break login) and if the reCaptcha shows up needing its clicks, I suspect Google might be the problem.