# password does not match on 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, password

for some reason, in recent weeks my customers are getting "password does not match" errors when making accounts etc.

I know there is a known issue on 1.9.1.0, but I am using 1.9.0.1

Does anyone have a fix or workaround that applies to 1.9.0.1?

Comment: Do you have a test customer with a password you know? Try creating a new customer and compare hashes. Might be a salt issue. Also, does resetting the password solve it?

Comment: the problem i've replicated so far is making a new account, and needing to enter the new password 2 times - thus getting the error. Not sure how I can check that hashes at that stage - the data isn't in the database.

Comment: so the user you create has an account without password in the database?

Please check the error logs for possible leads and think of any modules that might cause an error

Comment: sorry, to clarify - creating a new user account, via the "register" link, you then get the error. In the initial, create an account screen..  (so nothing in the DB at that stage - all new)

Comment: Are there any core rewrites?

Comment: not really sure (I'm not a dev). Is there a way to list them? How could I find that out? I have a few extensions running, for sure...

Comment: what is ur magento version ? are you sure its 1.9.0.1

Comment: Hi, control panel shows "Magento ver. 1.9.0.1"

Comment: Do you get the error on the client side (javascript validation) or server side (the page reloads and you get an error message at the top of the page) ?

Comment: the page reloads and the message is then 'above the form'  ... "Please make sure your passwords match." in a red box with large X (on my theme)

Comment: @egg could you check what the `name` attribute value is on the input of the second password box in the registration form?

Comment: it is "confirmation"

Comment: Make sure in login form there should be : <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />

Comment: for registering new accounts, where should I look? I checked "/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml" ... but that line of code is not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable template path hints and look in template for this line:

`<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>`

If this is missing, add it in your template file.

Comment: thanks, but can you clarify in which file and where that should be?

Comment: Enable template path hints and look your file path

Comment: Hi, so far, this is the closest to my solution. I followed the guide here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31933/customer-login-doesnt-work-in-1-9, and entered the following code into my register.phtml page <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" /> . This is basically what you are suggesting, right? I entered it mutliple times in that file, each time I found a <ul class="form-list"> ... not sure if thats overkill or correct - but for the moment, I can create a new account!! Success!!

Comment: I just wonder... is it really OK to edit the file in app\design\frontend\base\default\template\customer\form\register.phtml or should be making my own version of that?

Comment: ps. bounty awarded :)

Comment: @egg, you should only have to add that line once, right after the opening form tag. You should copy that file to your theme and make the changes there so that they are not overwritten by the next upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Search for `setConfirmation()` and `getConfirmation()` in your extensions and replace with `setPasswordConfirmation()` and `getPasswordConfirmation()`.

Or if they should stay compatible with older versions, use something like this:

```
$info = Mage::getVersionInfo();
$version = "{$info['major']}.{$info['minor']}.{$info['revision']}.{$info['patch']}";

if($version >= '1.9.1.0'){
$customer->setPasswordConfirmation($this->getRequest()->getPost('confirmation')); // just check the name of confirm password field in the registration form accordlingly add the name in the get Post
} else {
$customer->setConfirmation($this->getRequest()->getPost('confirmation')); // just check the name of confirm password field in the registration form accordlingly add the name in the get Post
}
```

Comment: for more info refer http://pradeepsanku.com/2015/05/15/please-make-sure-your-passwords-match-magento/

Comment: I added some explanation to your code snippet, hope it matches your intent.

Comment: thanks... but which file should this be inserted into?

Comment: see this link for more details http://pradeepsanku.com/2015/05/15/please-make-sure-your-passwords-match-magento/

Comment: Hi, in my Mage_Customer_Model_Customer.php I see the public function validate(), and within this: $confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();
        if ($password != $confirmation) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
        }.    Am i meant to overright this? Some clarity on where to enter your code would be great, thanks!!

Comment: yes rewrite this customer model.you can check how to rewrite an model online in magento

Comment: for testing, can I just insert the code... is that enough?

Comment: yes u can.after testing wther it is solved or not thn remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used any extension for checkout???

I had same error in firechecout extension then I change the following code,  set `$customer->setPasswordConfirmation` instead of `$customer->setConfirmation`  in `Model/Standered.php`

Comment: i'm using GOMAGE LightCheckout... I will see if I can find that file/code.. thanks

Comment: hii egg have you find the solution or not??

Comment: sorry... been in meetings all day - will try to troubleshoot in the morning and get back to you all! Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry... i'm unable to find any standard.php file which has this text in. Not sure if I look in the wrong place... but currently stuck. Any more tips?