# magento "Invalid login or password." for frontend customer after some hack

Tags: magento-1.9, security

**Initial version: 1.9.0.1**

Seems some hack issue suddenly my frontend customers were not able to login with correct password. I did change password from admin for user and tried to login, even that did not worked.

I also changed password in db put md5 value and tried it did not worked too.

Then I updated magento to 1.9.2.4, but still found same issue. I tried reindex, cleared cache.

Can you please tell steps to fix this?

Comment: Check the link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31933/customer-login-doesnt-work-in-1-9

Comment: why do you suspect a hack to be responsible for this bug?

Comment: can you guide way to fix it

Answer (score 1):

it is known issue after hack you might be in some cases `form_key` is not there

just open your phtml file and check for the form_key and if it is not there then add below line

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

Comment: it is there ,i there something like hash to check password changed ?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the first fix to try is resetting the customer's password within the admin: Customers>Manage Customers, Account Information>Send Auto-Generated Password, Save.

If that does not work, I would try the [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) application. Install per the instructions in the readme. There is an interactive command for this situation:

```
n98-magerun.phar customer:change-password
```