# Caching problem after login

Tags: login, caching

I am using FPC caching on my site. My problem is if customer visit some products page without login, and then want to write a review, he goes to login page and after log in when he come back to product page he wants to write review, he see the "You must be log in to write review" notice instead of review form. I need to clear cache by myself manually to show them logged in product page. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue after applying security patches.

Some of the phtml files will need a line of code adding to them. this is because there was something called a "form key" introduced in later versions of magento, and the security patches contain code from later versions than the one you are patching.

you will need to add the code to the login.phtml in your theme folder, also several other pages including the registration page and the forgotten password page.

After this, I found that the FPC was caching form keys also! so the only way to get actual unique form keys on each page was to disable the FPC extension. It has slowed down the site a little.

My answer is to first disable your FPC to make sure this is causing the problem. Then if it is, keep it disabled until you wither update the extension or migrate to magento 2.

source of information:

[Customer Login Doesn't Work in 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31933/customer-login-doesnt-work-in-1-9)

Comment: Thanks a lot I disabled FPC and added "<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />" into my login.phtml, now everything works well. By the way because of FPC remember me extension didn't work well.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.