# Customer Account Login Doesn't Work

Tags: magento-1.9, error, login, customer-account

The account login page isn't allowing customers to log in.
I tried what this article says [Customer Login Doesn't Work in 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31933/customer-login-doesnt-work-in-1-9)
but it's still not working.

It was working earlier, I could log in I added a logout link.
But now I cant log in anymore. I've flushed my magento cache,cache storage and browser cache but nothing is working.
Any ideas?

Comment: Checked the Magento cookie settings? Is CAPTCHA active in admin and does not appear in your theme?

Comment: if your site is live than give the url so we can check

Comment: I figured it out it was a cookie issue. System->configuration->general->web->session cookie management->Cookie Domain I had this field empty. You have to set it to www.{{your_site}}.com, clear your cookies and then it worked for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of user error. User stated that the problem was resolved in a comment, not a answer and this question is likely to become orphaned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out it was a cookie issue. System->configuration->general->web->session cookie management->Cookie Domain I had this field empty. You have to set it to www.{{your_site}}.com, clear your cookies and then it worked for me.