# Magento database documentation version 1.9.3.2

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I'm looking for **documentation** of the **Magento database v1.9**.

I once saw an online interactive tool that lets you browse the different versions of the database and look at table names and attributes. Can anyone give a URL for this or for other database documentation for 1.9.3.2?

I particularly need to find organization types and how they are stored for the customer account in the DB, also how the password for the customer account is stored. (Some of our custom code doesn't work after upgrade to 1932)

I found this so far
http://anna.voelkl.at/uploads/magento/ce1922.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Customer data organisation types and how they are stored

magento Customer modules is  using [Eav patten](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-7.html) for save Customer Data.

Customer  have using two types of entities customer and other customer_address entity

It complex way to save the data. Every fields customer entity,customer_address treated as Attribute.

Attributes are different types of  **text,varchar,int,decimal** etc.

Different type of  attribute, magento save customer  data receptive tables

```
customer_address_entity_datetime
customer_address_entity_decimal
customer_address_entity_int
customer_address_entity_text
customer_address_entity_varchar
customer_eav_attribute
customer_eav_attribute_website
customer_entity
customer_entity_datetime
customer_entity_decimal
customer_entity_int
customer_entity_text
customer_entity_varchar
```

If you understand ***EAV structure*** then you will *understand the Customer data*

### Password:

For password ,magento follow its own  hashlogic

Checkout more details at http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/how-does-magento-encrypt-and-validate-passwords/

### Regarding Login:

I guess that you may have issue in [form key Issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31933/customer-login-doesnt-work-in-1-9) instead of   credentail

Comment: I found this, which would have been very useful, but it stops at 1702 :-   http://www.magereverse.com/index/magento-sql-structure/version/1-7-0-2